# Exchange 2003 ActiveSync fine but GAL lookups not working

Tags: exchange-2003, activesync, exchange

We have Exchange 2003 SP2 and use ActiveSync for our mobile devices (iOS and sever Android versions). Everything works except for GAL lookups and we've confirmed that the devices and client versions we are trying it on are supposed to support it. The symptom is different depending on the client, but there is never an error. In a nutshell, lookups return no results. This was working previously and we aren't sure what has changed.

Are there logs in Exchange or IIS that will allow me to see GAL lookup transactions? Could it be a GAL permissions issue? (No issues with GAL in Outlook) Could it have been caused by upgrading our DCs to 2008 and increasing the forest/domain functional levels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Followed Method 2 of //support.microsoft.com/kb/817379:

1. Disabled forms-based authentication in System Manager
2. Cloned the /Exchange virtual directory as /Exchange-OMA-New
3. Changed registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\MasSync\Parameters\ExchangeVDir from /Exchange-OMA to /Exchange-OMA-New
4. Restarted all IIS services
5. Tested GAL lookup ok on four devices with various OS's and versions

NOTE: Turning off forms-based authentication cause our users to have to enter DOMAIN\username rather than just username for OWA. If this is undesirable, enable it in the same place as Step 1 and it will have no ill affects on GAL fix.